# Flutter: How can I implement Google Maps in locale language?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, flutter-web

I want to implement Google Maps in the locale language like the below image. How can I implement it in my Flutter app?

[image]

Comment: Have you started anything? Could you please provide the Flutter Google Maps package you're using?

Comment: @jabamataro I am using google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.6